# 'session' is undefined' with express.js

Tags: node.js, session, express

i'm using *express.session()* in my express app so i've created a middleware for authentication user before sending them to '/' my code is :

```
var express = require('express');

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.cookieParser('keyboard cat'));
  app.use(express.session( {secret : "my secret"}));
  app.use(app.router);
});

var accessChecker= function(req,res,next){
    if (req.session.user.name && req.session.auth){
    next(); 
    }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
    }
   }
app.get('/',accessChecker(), routes.index);
```

When i run this code i get this message :

```
if (req.session.user.name && req.session.auth){
       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined
```

i've tried to put ***accessChecker*** function before  ***app.configure***
and to use ***express.cookieParser()*** and ***express.session()*** inside ***acessChecker*** function but always i get the same message !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are invoking the `accessChecker` function rather passing a pointer to the function. This will fix the problem:

```
app.get('/', accessChecker, routes.index);
```

For more examples see the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB). I'd also suggest looking at [passport](http://passportjs.org/) if you want to do authentication.